# Create on-premise Service Fabric cluster fails with exception

Tags: cluster-computing, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to follow the instructions at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/#plan-and-prepare-for-cluster-deployment to create a dev cluster on a test machine. I am using the sample ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json file. However creation failed with following exception:

Create Cluster failed with exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceE
xception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterCmdletBase.NewCluster(String clusterConfigurationFilePath, String fabric
PackageSourcePath, Boolean rollbackOnFailure)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.d__0.MoveNext()<---

Is there any setting I missed?

The requirements appear to be met:
•Minimum of 2 GB memory is recommended
•Network connectivity – Make sure that the machines are on a secure network/or networks
•Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows Server 2012 (you need to have KB2858668 installed for this).
•.NET Framework 4.5.1 or higher, full install
•Windows PowerShell 3.0
•The cluster administrator deploying and configuring the cluster must have administrator privileges on each of the computers.
•RemoteRegistry service should be running on all the machines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found out that I need to uninstall Azure Service Fabric SDK. Apparently the cluster machine used for testing are not meant to be used to developer Service Fabric Applications or Services?